# Is there a way to filter the RSS view of a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, rss, moss

I'm trying to get only certain items from a SharePoint list.  The RSS feed is giving me everything, even if I have the list filtered of looking at a specific view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some more digging around [revealed](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=94) that yes, you can get an RSS feed for a specific view. The link is on the "Edit View" page. It effectively adds the view GUID to the url.